# Как сделать так чтобы контент мог просматривать только тот пользователь который его создал?

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
VIEWS.PY

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status, permissions, generics
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import TaskSerializer, ListSerializer
from .models import Task

class ViewListPermission(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated] 

class taskList(ViewListPermission):
    @api_view(['GET'])
    def taskList(request):
        tasks = Task.objects.all()
        serializer = ListSerializer(tasks, many = True)
        return  Response(serializer.data)

SERIALAIZER.PY

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Task

class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('title','deadline','completed','importance','id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам надо сделать custom permissions, что то типа такого:

```
permission_classes = [permissions.CustomPermissions] 

# permissions.py
class CustomPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.user == obj.user:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```